# augmented reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I've been assigned a project to develop an application based on Augmented Reality (AR).
They are about to give me an Android phone in few days, but I do not know anything about AR. I don't know where to start!

Can anyone suggest what should be the first thing I do to learn about AR and about what will be required to do to develop this type of application?

Comment: Download AR applications, try them out, find out what exactly it is you need to do, then ask more specific questions. (Not necessarily in that order)

Comment: This question is much too vague. It would require a superheroic amount of effort to answer this question accurately.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do would be to download the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and start going through their [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/index.html). You won't be able to do much augmented reality stuff without first understanding the basics of the SDK and how Android development works.

Comment: hey it was typing mistake in asked question..let me correct it..consider Augmented Reality instead argument reality..

Comment: Do you know how to use the Android SDK and access the camera stream?

Comment: no..i reali dont know how to work with that...

Comment: Have you got the Android SDK installed and created other basic apps?

Comment: This is it. You should install it and go through the introduction tutorials. These will explain how to use the various features of the Android device. Once you understand this, you'll be able to get your app to access the camera and develop an AR app. Here's the `Camera` class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: ok....i would like to start now having things needed u discussed...thanks a lot sir..

Comment: No problem. Download the SDK from the link in my answer, then read the introduction in the other link. This should help you get started with understanding the basics. You can then start accessing various features like the camera (I linked in my previous comment). One step at a time :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a linked in group for mobile augmented reality called "Mobile Augmented Reality".  I suggest that you start by joining that group and going through the discussion threads.

From a coding standpoint, I recommend that you familiarize yourself with the OpenCV project ( http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ ), which is an open source library for computer vision.  Depending on the project, you may also need to learn about

- camera capabilities of your platform
- combining live video feeds with generated graphics or images
- various sensors (magnetometer, accelerometer)
- location based frameworks

I know that this sounds like a lot of different disciplines, but that's part of what makes this field interesting and challenging.

There are a number of different apps that use augmented reality that you'll want to check out.  I'm not sure what's available for Android, but on the iPhone you could start with the "Monocle" feature on the Yelp app, and the app "Word Lens" -- both of these may be on Android.